# Will I lose the software I have on 13.04 if I install 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04

I have many software like the TuxPaint, tux type, text editor , devhelp , recordmydesktop etc on my Ubuntu 13.04.

Will I loose these software if I install Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

You will lose any programs you downloaded, but all those programs you mentioned were in 12.10. While you can keep your software when you are doing an upgrade, there isn't really an official downgrade process, so you will have to re-download any software you want. However, if you wait only a few more weeks, 13.04 will be completed, so if you are downgrading because of bugs, please report them and then see if they disappear in the final release.